# show total stock available

Tags: product, cataloginventory

Is there a simple way to show total quantity in stock for products. We are trying to make it a simple inventory catalog showing products and total quantity available per product?

If some development is needed, how much roughly will someone charge to make these two changes, brand new 2.17 installation, a small business with no in house support. Second choice we have to move to open cart

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Where you want to show total stock? Frontend product detail page?

Comment: Yes. Front end please. Sorry I checked my message a bit late.